# Why Javascript throws this error

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have following javascript in which I want assign value of str to hidden field "abc" in form "form".
It produces value of str in alert box but when I try to assign that value to abc using
"document.forms[form].abc.value=str;"
Then throws following error...

```
Message: 'document.forms.form.abc' is null or not an object
Line: 140
Char: 5
Code: 0
```

The variable image_url contains one url which is dynamically generated such as `http://localhist/local/..../1234.jpg`

How Do I get rid on this...

```
<script language="JavaScript">
        function imgurl()
        {
            var str=image_url;
            alert("Image Stored @"+str);

            document.forms["form"].abc.value=str;
            //document.getElementById('url').innerHTML=str;

        }
    </script>


 <form name="form">
    <input type="button" value="URL" onclick="javascript:imgurl();">
                            </td><br>
            <td valign=top>
                <div id="upload_results" style="border:2px black"></div><br/>
                <input type="hidden" name="abc" value="">
                <br/><p id="url"/>
            </td>
            </tr>
    </form>
```

Comment: I'm surprised that you don't get the error "`image_url` is not defined" (or similar). If I fix this, **your code works fine** (in Chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/7rMbj/

Comment: no I won't get it because it reffered as global varible which is defined in fuction above imgurl().

Comment: Just another thing: you don't need to add `javascript:` prefix before calling `imgurl()`. Without it this code will work fine.

Comment: You should always provide self contained examples (http://sscce.org/), this makes it easier for us to work with it. Anyways, since this is clarified and the code you posted is correct, the problem is somewhere else and you'd need to provide more information if you want help. @Sayem: Agreed, `javascript:` there is unnecessary, `foo:` would have the same effect, but it is not an error and the code will work the same, with or without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ids.

```
<input type="hidden" id="abc" name="abc" value="">
```

JavaScript:

```
function imgurl() {
    document.getElementById("abc").value = img_url;
}
```

Comment: Why is that a better solution?

Comment: Much faster on the browser and allows you to directly go to an element rather than relying on its parent.

Comment: as I assign image_url to str variable I used it like this
document.getElementById("abc").value=str;
This not throwing error but how do I check if value assigned or not?

Comment: You can alert the value afterwards. `alert("Value is: " + document.getElementById("abc").value);`

Comment: Sorry...sorry...I  recovered from error retreive value in hidden field.
Many Many Thanks ....

Comment: @yatin If the solution worked for you, you should accept the answer. Not doing so, will discourage us.

Comment: @yatin You have to check the "green tick mark" next to my answer in order to "accept" it :)